# Pandas - How To Read From The Nth Column of a Table

Tags: python, pandas

My code gets into a wikipedia page, and prints the table I want. However, say i want the nth, n-1, and n-2 columns of this table.

How can i do this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
val=[]
webPage=driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_the_United_States#Data')
df=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_the_United_States#Data')[1]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```
df.iloc[:, n]
```

For the last column, you can use

```
df.iloc[:, -1]
```

Example

```
>>> df
   0  1  2   3
0  1  2  9  10
1  3  4  8  11
2  5  6  7  12

>>> df.iloc[:,  -3:]
   1  2   3
0  2  9  10
1  4  8  11
2  6  7  12
```

Comment: What if I want the last 3 together? So last column, second to last column, and third to last column?

Comment: Read pandas documentation. `df.iloc[:, -3:]`

Comment: df.iloc[:,  -3:] only prints the n-3 column. I want a table of the last 3 columns